# What is open-in-browser package keyboard shortcut in Atom on Windows?

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor, atom-editor

I am using Atom on Windows.

I would like to use a keyboard shortcut to open my HTML page in a browser but I can't find such a shortcut for Windows. Is there a shortcut in Atom for this?

Comment: FYI you can use the [command palette](https://atom.io/packages/command-palette) to find available commands

Comment: thanks jonrsharpe your comment is very useful i get the command the shortcut is Ctrl + Alt + Q but it is also dosent work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl-Alt-Q` on the open HTML file, according to [the official site](https://atom.io/packages/open-in-browser). Curiously, there are some reports of the shortcut not working so it could be a windows bug, works fine on OSX, at least v0.4.7.

[image: Source here]

Another way to check the shortcut is to look for it on atom's command palette (ctrl-shift-p):

[image]

If the specified shortcut still won't work and you wish to try to manually bind it, you can try opening atom's keymap.cson file:

[image]

and try setting the following in the keymap.cson file:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-alt-q': 'open-in-browser:open'
```

[image]

Save the file and try the shortcut.

[Atom's manual in-depth information about keymaps](http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/#keymaps-in-depth)

Comment: thanks for your help, But Ctrl + Alt + Q  doesnt work and i want keyboard shortcut Not right click the file on the sidebar.

Comment: according to this [link] (https://github.com/ehuss/atom-column-select/issues/2) i supposed to edit in file called **column-select.cson** but i cant find this file.

Comment: where is the package :) ?

Answer (score 0):

I added this lines in keymap.
When I click in Editor and I also click workspace, It works well.

```
'atom-workspace':
  'ctrl-e': 'open-in-browsers:toggle'
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-e': 'open-in-browsers:toggle'
```